# Color specific axis tick label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to color a specific axis tick label when calling in a custom function. For example, take this graph:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to color the xaxis tick label 6 with "red". You can color the `axis.text.x` with `element_text` in your `theme` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c("black", "red", 'black')))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But of course, this isn't really automatic and smooth. Here is a starting point for a custom function:

```
color_axis_tick_label <- function(df, xaxis, xaxistick) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor({{xaxis}}))) +
    geom_bar()
}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this in a more automatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `ggtext::element_markdown` and a custom function for the `labels` argument of the scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

color_axis_tick_label <- function(df, xaxis, xaxistick) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor({{ xaxis }}))) +
    scale_x_discrete(
      labels = ~ ifelse(.x %in% xaxistick,
        paste0("<span style='color: red'>", .x, "</span>"), .x
      )
    ) +
    geom_bar() +
    theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
}

color_axis_tick_label(mtcars, cyl, 6)
```

[image]